# Pandas query cell containing an array

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am trying to return results of a Dataframe based on the rows matching an array.

The cell contains an array like this:

```
[[x1, y1], [x2, y2], ...]
```

Currently I'm trying to do the following:

```
queryArray = np.array([[x1, y1], [x2, y2], ...])
df.query("colname == [@queryArray]")
```

However I just get an empty Dataframe with no results returned.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

We assume that we have data like that:

```
                 column
0  [[x1, y1], [x2, y2]]
1  [[x1, y1], [x2, y2]]
2              [x7, y7]
3              [x8, y8]
4                  smth
5                   435
```

If I understand you need to clean your df leaving only arrays objects which size = (2,2). So you want to get first 2 rows (0 - 1). For this purpose we create additional column ['column2'] where we check type and len of data in every row. If type and len is like we need, we get True, if not we get False. Next step we just drop this additional column.

```
df['column2'] = df.apply(lambda x: type(x.column).__module__ == np.__name__ and x.column.shape == (2, 2), axis=1)
df = df.loc[df['column2'] == True].drop(columns=['column2'])
```

After that we get only rows which we were looking for:

```
                 column
0  [[x1, y1], [x2, y2]]
1  [[x1, y1], [x2, y2]]
```

Now, we can unpack this data for every row from numpy format to pandas:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(*df['column']))).T
```

And our df looks like that:

```
          0         1
0  [x1, y1]  [x2, y2]
1  [x1, y1]  [x2, y2]
```

If you want you can unpack it further.

Comment: I am already doing:
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["colname"])

x = np.array([ [x1,y1],[x2,y2]... ])

loop till N
    df.loc[len(df.index)] = [x]

to populate the Dataframe
Is this what you meant?

Comment: Hmm, i suspect that I don't know what you exactly need. If you need numpy to pandas dataframe you have to just run code above. If you want to filter it you can do it in pandas and return to numpy with result. You can also use np.where if you can stay with numpy object. Please explain again what you need, because i think didn't catch it.

Comment: So I have a Dataframe where an entry contains an array within a single cell (my understanding is that pandas uses Numpy arrays).

Something like this:
Index, data, array
0: data, [ [x1, y1], [x2,y2]... ]
1: data, [ [x1, y1], [x2,y2]... ]
etc...


Currently I have the Dataframe implemented, and I can see that this cell is storing the data as array objects.

what I want to do is get all rows where the cell containing the array matches a query array.

Answer (score 0):

found a solution using
df[ df['col_name'].apply(lambda x: np.array_equal(queryArray, x)]